# Propagating losses in multimodal data model with joint fusion

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, multimodality

I am building a model that combines imaging and structured data together. We plan on using a joint fusion architecture where we first process the images into nx1 vector using a CNN. We'll then combine this with the structured data and pass it through a NN (see fig 2 of this [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41746-020-00341-z)). We know we should propagate the loss from the output to the CNN model but are unsure how. Do we pass the whole loss back to the CNN model or something else? We are implementing in pytorch.

Thanks a lot!